# How to change text couple times and save every single one?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, automation, data-merge

Is there a way to make really quickly ID's for events?

I have a background for my ID's but I have to make them one at a time and save it for each person on the list.

Can I somehow automate this process?

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE Yamashi. Can you elaborate on your problem a bit more to clear up some details? Are you constrained to only using Bridge and Photoshop?

Comment: I edited your question to better reflect what I _think_ you are trying to acomplish. Feel free to rollback the edits if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Thanks for editing. You got what I wanted :D
I know that in bridge there are options to change many images at one, so I thought that maybe there is one for text, but I am not constrained to using only Bridge and PS.
For clearing my problem:

Comment: In Photoshop you can do this using [data sets](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-data-driven-graphics.html). -  I googled for a few video tutorials: [This seemed pretty good, but perhaps unnecessarily complicated tutorial for a beginner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lsPD9rLwJjc) **and** [this seemed a bit easier to understand since the document/data set is simpler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IzpItHTvyo).

Comment: @Yamashi If you have access to InDesign that would be the far simpler program to leverage its data merge capabilities.

Comment: 1st video tutorials from Joonas is really helpful. I didn't know about data sets.

Answer (score 1):

You could use built in data merge in InDesign.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MXSoMenTW88

Comment: Hi Ahmet, welcome to GD.SE. We like long answers here that don't solely rely on links because they can go dead. Can you edit your answer and give a breakdown of what that video entails?

Comment: Sorry I can't explain it very well, my english isn't good enough. Also I gave a link from Linked-in youtube channel. Chance of it getting removed are very slim.

Comment: That's ok, try your best and we can help you get your answer across! The point of the SE sites is for the asker to be able to find their answer **_on the site_** rather than going off-site.